# Synchronize 2 threads in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization, locking

I have 2 methods, each on a different thread.

While Method1 is on its critical section, Method2 needs to wait.
Notice that Method2 runs constantly and needs to wait ONLY in case Method1 is operating on its critical section. Otherwise, just continue with its work..

How do I do that?

Pseudo-Code:

```
Method1
{
       Announce the entrence to critical-section
       ......Do some stuff.........
       Announce the leaving of critical-section
}


Method2
{
       Method1 is in its critical-section? - WAIT TILL IT DONE
       ......Do some stuff...........
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me edit this because it's only a one character diff, but it's a very important one character diff: you should change the pseudo code inside of Method2 to say "Method1 is in its critical-section" (not Method2 is in its critical section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a condition variable to reliably control the behavior between 2 threads. Technically you can do what the other answers suggest with just sharing a variable but it will fall apart quickly in other scenarios.

```
BOOL isMethod1Busy = NO;
NSCondition *method1Condition = [[NSCondition alloc] init]

- (void)method1
{
    [method1Condition lock];
    isMethod1Busy = YES;

    // do work

    isMethod1Busy = NO;
    [method1Condition signal];
    [method1Condition unlock];
}

- (void)method2
{
    [method1Condition lock];
    while (isMethod1Busy) {
        [method1Condition wait];
    }

    // do stuff while method1 is not working

    [method1Condition unlock];
}
```

Comment: Just for my own understanding, in what other scenarios will a simple boolean fall apart?

Comment: Is not the solution missing an `isMethod1Busy = NO` before it exits the conditional region? @pcperini: a simple boolean doesn't work as you can't wait for a variable's value to change, you have to "busy wait" or "poll" checking periodically - both are much poorer solutions in general to proper waiting.

Comment: @CRD Ok, I buy polling vs. alerts as a good reason to use NSConditions. But ultimately nothing will break, just lack possible efficiency.

Comment: Fixed the issue with not setting the boolean. Banking on the boolean to be atomic may work in the situation you're in, but there's no guarantee in your simple snippet that method1 doesn't start back up after you've passed the check saying that it isn't busy. That's also banking on whatever information you need to share between threads being atomic. If it isn't then you must use the condition or another lock.

Comment: I get a deadlock here. method1 is calling 'lock' and right afterwards method2 is calling its 'lock'..

Comment: Is it possible that I'm not operating on different threads?! Method2 is actually a delegate for NSURLConnection..

Comment: The example is stripped from the docs, I just renamed some variables to be accurate to your question. And yes, `NSURLConnection` (as well as most other asynchronous calls) executes delegates on the main thread, not on a background thread via the `[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:]` API.

Answer (score 0):

Besides noting that architecturally, you should probably be designing your software to be event-based instead of what you have here, I'd posit that you could use NSNotificationCenter to do the "announcing" part in Method1.

Another thing you could do, caveats above considered, is set a BOOL on the instance saying it should skip processing:

```
-(void)method2 {

    if (self.skipProcessing)
        return;

    //normal code here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some shared variable (assigned somewhere logically above both Methods) to synchronize the methods.

Here, I'm assuming you're using something like `NSThread` to handle your threading.

```
- (void)Method1:
{
    self.SYNC_LOCK = YES;
    // do some stuff
    self.SYNC_LOCK = NO;
}

- (void)Method2:
{
    if (self.SYNC_LOCK) {return;}
    // do some stuff
}
```

If you're also looking for a simply threading library, you should take a look at Grand Central Dispatch. I've got a library ([GCD - GitHub](https://github.com/pcperini/GCD/blob/master/GCD.m)) that wraps these sort of things up nicely.

```
- (void)Method1
{
    [GCD doInBackground: ^{
        self.SYNC_LOCK = YES;
        // do some stuff
        self.SYNC_LOCK = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)Method2
{
    void (^stuff_block)(void) = ^{
        while (!self.SYNC_LOCK) {sleep(SOME_WAIT_TIME);}
        //do some stuff
    };
    [GCD doInBackground: stuff_block every: FEW_SECONDS];
}
```

Comment: I don't think the first suggestion is a solution to the original problem, it return's rather than waits. The second is probably not a good solution as it polls rather than waits.